# Google Sheets - Script - Condition if a range is empty

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to put a condition if a range of cells is empty. All the cells must be strictly empty. So I tried this :

```js
if ( bottomcolumn.getValues() == '') {
```

(upcolumn is a variable range i created)

It does'nt work. I think i didn't well understand the google user guide... Any ideas ?

Thank you for reading...

Comment: How about [Range.isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isBlank())...Returns true if the range is totally blank.

Comment: You're right... Thank you Cooper :) I was looking for some complicated solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try do see what bottomcolumn.getValues() actually returns and then work from there, I assume it may be null or undefined.

So do this to understand what it outputs:

```
console.log( bottomcolumn.getValues() )
```

and then for your condition just check if it is a falsy value, such as 0, null, undefined, empty string, etc…:

```
if( !bottomcolumn ){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advices Neven Subotic :) I will use your method next time.

Comment: sure, put a checkmark next to my comment to resolve this question.